# How to hide a class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have text on a page, its in a `<h3>` tag, which has a class `ms-standardheader`, but there are other texts on the page with the same class in its own `<h3>` tag. I also know the text I want to hide is 'Session'.

With this how can I write a javascript function to hide only this text?

Here is an image of the developtools from IE.

[image]

Comment: I added a pictire above to show you. Also I havent trried anything yet because i dont know what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, if you're restricted (as your tags suggest) to non-library plain JavaScript, the following:

```
var h3s = document.getElementsByTagName('h3'),
    classedH3 = [];

for (var i = 0, len = h3s.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (h3s[i].className.indexOf('ms-standardheader') > -1) {
        classedH3.push(h3s[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0, len = classedH3.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (classedH3[i].firstChild.nodeValue == 'the text to hide'){
        classedH3[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8hxha/).

References:

- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className).
- [`node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue).
- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: That will error. You can't call `getElementsByClassName` on a *NodeList*.

Comment: That it won't; somehow that slipped my mind when I wrote the answer. On the bright side I would've probably remembered when testing in the JS Fiddle. But...maybe not. Thanks! =) @sneaky: see the now-edited answer. It should work, but might need adapting if you're using IE?

Comment: Its still not working, maybe it has something to do with the text Session being split into different lines (based on the pic) although on screen, it appears like 'Session'.

Comment: Possibly. Could you post the actual html (in text)? Rather than a picture of it?

Comment: I figured it out with this: see below comment

Answer (score 0):

Can't you give the target element an ID? That would make things much more simple. Otherwise, you have to go through all `<h3>` elements until you find the one you want to hide:

```
var headings = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
for(var i=0; i<headings.length; i++) {
    var contentElement = headings[i].getElementsByTagName('nobr');
    var content = "";
    if(contentElement.length) {
        content = contentElement[0].textContent ? contentElement[0].textContent : contentElement[0].innerText;
    }
    var content = contentElement.length ? contentElement[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue : '';
    if(headings[i].className == 'ms-standardheader' && content == 'Session') {
         headings[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a picture above that may make you change the code u put, sine this didnt work. Also I can't edit the page, I can only add css and/or javascript to it...

Comment: Updated again, try new version

Comment: I just tried it again and headings.length is coming out to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this :

```
 window.onload = function()
  {
      getElementByClass('ms-standardheader');
  }

window.getElementByClass = function(theClass){

 var allHTMLTags=document.getElementsByTagName('*');

  for (i=0; i<allHTMLTags.length; i++) {
       if (allHTMLTags[i].className==theClass) {
               var content  = allHTMLTags[i].innerHTML;
               var search = /session/;
               if (search.test(content))
                  {
                     alert(search);
                     allHTMLTags[i].style.display='none';     
                  }
             }
        }
 }
```

**See Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/3ETpf/18/

Answer (score 0):

Always favour a unique Id where possible. If not possible then you have to manually traverse the DOM to find the elements you are looking for. Here's an example using `getElementsByTagName()`.

```
var i, header, headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i += 1) {
    header = headers[i];
    if (header.className === 'ms-standardheader' &&
            (header.textContent || header.innerText) === 'Session') {
        header.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/whP5z/

Answer (score -1):

If you have jquery you may type this :

```
$("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Session')").hide();
```

Comment: Unfortunetly I dont have jquery.

Comment: So you'll have to implement the search yourself. bfvaretto's code seems correct at first sight.

Comment: Hu ? Why this downvote ? I was the first to answer, I made a correct answer, what's the deal ?